# String.equals("a string") || String.equalsIgnoreCase("a string")

Tags: java, string

I have a function..

```
containsIgnoreCase(searchIn, seachFor)
```

When you use the Java function equals or equalsIgnoreCase you send the searchIn String in front of the function.

EXAMPLE 1:

```
searchIn.equals(searchFor)
```

I want to be able to do similar for my function.

EXAMPLE 2:

```
searchIn.containsIgnoreCase(searchFor);
```

Q1: Is there a special name that the String at the beginning is called?

Q2: Is there any way I can call my function with the String at the beginning?

Comment: No, you can't do this.  `String` is a `final` class, which means you make a subclass with new methods in it.

Comment: I don't know, what is the string at the beginning?

Comment: @Elliott - he means, is there a special word for the object on which the method is called.

Comment: @DavidWallace you're missing a "can't" in your comment

Comment: I think @DavidWallace comment is enough to answer your questions

Comment: Haha, @PurpleVermont, you're right.  Let me try again.  "`String` is a `final` class, which means you CAN'T make a subclass of it with new methods".   Ta da!

Comment: @DavidWallace Invocation target?

Comment: @Elliott Yeah, that'll do!

Comment: As @DavidWallace says, you can't do that; you should make your method "static" and call it on the two String arguments.

Comment: @DavidWallace Alright thanks. Do you by chance know what the string at the beginning is called (So I know how to refer to it in the future without seeming like a complete idiot)?

Comment: @Dustin - Elliott suggested "invocation target".  That works for me.

Comment: @PurpleVermont Yeah, it is a static method. I was just wanting to do it the way I call the other ones just for OCDs sake.

Comment: I don't think Elliott was intending to be obnoxious.  He/she just didn't understand your question and was asking for clarification.

Comment: Ah, well either way.. I feel satisfied with the answers. Thanks again.

Comment: @Dustin if there's nothing special going on in your method, you could just call `toLowerCase()` on both strings and then just use the built-in `contains` method?

Answer (score 0):

do like this

```
public boolean containsIgnoreCase(searchIn, seachFor){
      return searchIn.toLowerCase().contains(seachFor.toLowerCase());
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  OP says he's already written this (or something equivalent to it).

Comment: I've already gotten the function for containsIgnoreCase written, I was wondering if/how I could call it similar to how I can str.equals(str).